# SyntaxError in PostsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
C:/Users/Sergey/forum/app/views/posts/_form.html.haml:2: syntax error, unexpected ')' ));}\n#{_hamlout.format_script... ^ 
C:/Users/Sergey/forum/app/views/posts/_form.html.haml:5: unterminated string meets end of file 
C:/Users/Sergey/forum/app/views/posts/_form.html.haml:5: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

**_form.html.haml**:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
=f.input :title
=f.input :content
=f.submit
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, first of all StackOverflow is not your debug tool. Second add description of your problem. To write the good question please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

Haml is very strict in indentation. spaces do matter and do not use tabs.the code which is indented like below should work. Try erb first(if haven't already) and later move to haml.

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content
  = f.submit
```